# MouseWheel not working when published movie has wmode="transparent"?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, wmode

I'm experiencing a bug with a published flash movie. When I embed the movie in an HTML page (with SWFObject 2.1), and assing it the wmode param value of 'transparent', all my functions based on the MouseWheel event stop working. The movie is based on AS2. Anyone familiar with this bug?

Comment: I think I've run into this in the past, when I have some time I'll look deeper into it.  Favorited for now...

Comment: Is it just when the mouse is inside of the flash object, or for the whole page? The reason I ask is because embedded videos in a web page always seem to behave that way. Load up youtube and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround at Adobe Developer Connection:

[Workaround to support mouse wheel for FireFox with wmode](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=13086)

Comment: Not the most elegant work-around, but hey.. it does the job :) Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone involved in this case would care to describe the accepted workaround (by brunombrizi) as the link seems to be redirected to main page at Adobe Forums. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Mousewheel doesn't work for me either in AS3 when I set wmode=transparent.  Furthermore, my flash application acts really strange and crashes frequently with wmode=transparent.

Plus, it doesn't seem to work at all on firefox under linux... the flash app is always above everything.

I would not recommend using wmode=transparent unless your app is for a very specific browser and you have done extensive testing.