# Disable flash content using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable one web page from user interaction on click of a button.But my web page contains one iframe which contains some flash content.Now using jQuery when I am disabling the page the flash portion is still intearctive.How can I do this using jQuery ?

Comment: You mean disable like, pause? Or do you need to just hide it?

Comment: I need it to behave as jQuery modal

Comment: So you mean disable like, it's visible, can run, but the user shouldn't be able to interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to create  gray div which will cover whole flash object z-index is greater than flash objects z-index . When you disable page move just show this div .

making z-index work on flash is different story and also bit tricky, answer can be found here :
http://www.flashdesignerzone.com/tutorials/t1026.php

or here :

http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/

trick is to add parameter to flash object : WMODE opaque

Comment: Problem is that it can have knock on affects with mouse wheel actions when u use opaque. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477426/issues-with-wmode-opaque-and-issues-with-wmmode-window